# What is this java conditional doing?

Tags: java, math

I made a nine game puzzle in Java. The goal is get the numbers back in order. Game board below is stored in a 2d `ArrayList`. The game looks like:

```
2 5 1
3 6 7
4 8
```

A valid move would 7 or 8, in which case the blank space will swap with the selected number. 6 would not be valid, nor any numbers 1 - 6 in this state. The first way I coded my `isValidMove` function was a nightmare of nested switch & conditionals. I came across somebody else's code and it works perfectly for me. This is the code that replaced my nested mess:

```java
int differenceX = Math.abs(empty1 - move1);
int differenceY = Math.abs(empty2 - move2);
if (differenceX <= 1 && differenceY <= 1 && !(differenceX == 1 && differenceY == 1))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I understand what's happening until the `&& !(differenceX == 1 && differenceY == 1))`.
Checking the absolute value of the difference is 0 or 1 makes sense. It then seems to be also checking that the difference is not equal to 1. I presume this has something to do with ensuring a number like 6 isn't considered valid. Can someone please explain what is happening here? My brain hurts.

Comment: It's saying if the difference of X and Y are both less or equal to 1 but both cannot equal 1 at the same time

Comment: In addition to @Phaelaxz comment, it means that you can't move by diagonal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the conditional out of the if and it might make more sens :

```
int differenceX = Math.abs(empty1 - move1);
int differenceY = Math.abs(empty2 - move2);

boolean isNearHorizontal = differenceX <= 1;
boolean isNearVertical = differenceY <= 1;
boolean isNearDiagonal = differenceX == 1 && differenceY == 1;

// is near horizontally and vertically and not diagonally !
if ( isNearHorizontal && isNearVertical && !isNearDiagonal )
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

It does the same thing but might be easier to read to you.

By the way, Here is a trick many programmers catch on after a little while to further ease code reading

```
if (statement)
    return true
return false
```

is equivalent to

```
return statement
```